# How to bind database record with Label and show in Ajax Model Popup in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

My Database record is correctly bound with the Label but it doesn't show in Ajax Modal Popup.

**ASPX Code :**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PopUp.aspx.cs" Inherits="PopUp" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <style type="text/css">
    .modalBackground
    {
        background-color: Black;
        filter: alpha(opacity=90);
        opacity: 0.4;
    }
    .modalPopup
    {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        border-width: 3px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: black;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        width: 300px;
        height: 140px;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" runat="server" Interval="2000">
                </asp:Timer>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" BehaviorID="mpe" runat="server"
    PopupControlID="pnlPopup" TargetControlID="lbl_ltr_nmbr" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID = "btnHide">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none">
    <div class="header">
        Modal Popup
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="body">
       <asp:Label ID="lbl_ltr_nmbr" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnHide" runat="server" Text="Recieve" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Aspx.cs Code :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class PopUp : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Not Refreshed Yet";
    }
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand("CountLetterNumber", DatabaseConnection.OpenConnection());
        sqlcom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        string ltrnmbr = Convert.ToString(sqlcom.ExecuteScalar());
        lbl_ltr_nmbr.Text = "You are Recieved " + ltrnmbr + "new Letter";
        ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
    }
}
```

**Stored Procedure :**

[image: My stored procedure]

**Modal Popup :**

[image: The resulting modal popup]

I want to bind the database value with the label by updating its value after some delay using an Ajax Timer and show its value in the Modal Popup. Anyone help me , i will be very thankfull to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but your timer tick event will not affect your label because your timer is wrapped in an update panel. I think your label and your timer have to be housed in the same panel.

Comment: Yes , tnx a lot , this working now correctly for me, very goooooooooood